# Automatic page refresh even we navigate to another page

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem in page navigating. please help me to solve out.

in one asp.net page forexample Page1.aspx i have dropdown when we select an item in dropdown that would display in a label. Then we navigate to another page from page1.aspx to page2.aspx by clicking linkbutton in page1.aspx. Again if i come to page1.aspx that previously selected value of dropdown should appear in label.

please help me.

Comment: You can save the last selected value in a **session** or **view-state**. You can have a look **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol.  This means that it'll forget anything that you don't tell it to specifically ask it to.

When going back to Page1.aspx, your program has no idea what was selected before.

In terms of persisting user choices, you should look into storing them in Session ( or alternatively, cookies ) and checking for a pre-existing choice when returning to Page1.aspx.

If you have a saved value for the user at that point, you'll be able to set the correct value during the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

If it is like a wizard, I suggest you use a wizard control in the same page.

here is an example,
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103244/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061406-1.aspx